# Pull and push files via git commands

Tags: git, file, server, command

I'm new in git and having queries in using git commands.

I have created a git repo with two branches and I'm following the below procedures while cloning it into local:

```
 git clone URL
 git checkout -b dev
 git pull origin dev
```

After pulling the code, I will follow the below steps to add the files and commit:

```
git add <file path>
git commit -m "description"
git push origin dev
```

In the server end, I will run the below command in root directory:

git pull origin dev

My doubt is that what happen if I run the pull command from server, the old code will be removed from server or it will just override?

Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: You talk about *the* server, but then you mention doing `git pull` on this server. Pull connects to a server—well, to some other Git, anyway, but that's usually one on a server that serves Git stuff—and gets commits from it. So does your setup involve *two* servers, one for Git and one for whatever service you're providing? In this case you are actually working with *three* Git repositories: one on your laptop, one on a Git server, and one on a third server.

Answer (score 2):

git pull is to get the latest commits in the remote repository .

git push will push all the commits in your local repository to remote repository i.e server end .

Infact git clone alone from the repository is sufficient , because cloning is done directly from the remote repository and hence the latest .

Answer (score 1):

What happened in this case here is that the previous line of codes from the server is been replaced by your local change(s) made when you push. However, you can be able to see exactly the change you pushed as to the one in the server. It's always a good practice to always pull first before you commit and push your local changes.

Comment: Thanks. But in the server end, we have to run only the pull command, right?

Comment: Right. This link could be very helpful for you https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html